# Hibernate Bulk loading from excel: suggestions for design or approach for better performance

Tags: java, spring, excel, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am using Spring MVC,Hibernate for my Web Application.I am loading the data from excel using Apache POI.I am successfully able to load the data,But I think that my Approach is not efficient in terms of performance and memory.
I am explaining what I am doing currecty and What I think will improve the performance.

1. Using POI I am reading the sheet and then Read iterate each row and then iterate over columns.
2. During this single row iteration,I create a DTO and transfer it to service which provides transcation and calls DAO layer(which basically calls the save() method ).if the data is already present or its not valid,then exception is thrown and I know which Excel row had problem in data.
   Its kind of like validation of data also.
3. Then I iterate another row and perform step 2 again.

**Here is why I think My approach is wrong and for which I want you to suggest If am right or wrong.**

1. I am not reading all the data from the excel at one ,instead I am calling service and DAO on each row which wastes time in switching between methods.
2. Since the data is to be saved in the database without modifying ,so it should be directly loaded into the database instead of first creating a object and then saving persisting it.I am not doing bulk and batch operations.

**Here is what I think I should do:**

1. First fetch all the data from excel and store it in some collection.
2. Then I will iterate over the collection and during the iteration ,I will use that object to provide data to HQL and execute the query.
3. Is this the right approach to execute many insert queries within one transaction?
4. **Are all the queries executed or synchronized with the database when I commit the transaction?If yes,then won't the Persistence context be of large size?**
5. does this confirm to bulk operation in hibernate?

What do you say guys?your suggestions Please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current implementation is the correct way to do it. One change that needs to be made is to combine a bunch of rows in a single transaction, instead of updating/inserting each row in a separate transaction.  This way hibernate will use the jdbc batch update/insert to reduce the number of database round trips.

If the total number of rows can be huge then you should either break it up into multiple transaction or use a periodic flush & clear - so that the objects in the persistence context are pushed to the database and those objects become eligible for garbage collection.

Loading all data in memory and the processing is not a good idea.  If the data set size is huge you will run into out of memory issues.

This section from the hibernate reference has more details and other options.
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html